# Como fazer o codigo ler input negativo - C

Tags: c, array, for

Olá!
Estou fazendo um exercício e me deparei com esse problema:
Quando vou testar e coloco um número negativo ele não reconhece que o número é negativo.
Algúem consegue me ajudar?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    float vetor[6];
   
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        printf("Digite o %dº número: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &vetor[i]);
        
        if(vetor > 0){
            printf("\nNumero invalido. Digite somente numeros negativos.");
            return 0;
        }else{
            printf("\nOk, continue");
        }
        
    }
    printf("O resultado é:");
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        printf(" - %f ", vetor[i]);
        
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele não está reconhecendo devido a forma com que você usou o vetor na primeira comparação, você não especificou qual espaço do vetor está sendo comparado.

Deveria estar especificando o espaço, como:

```
    if(vetor[i] > 0){
          printf("\nNumero invalido. Digite somente numeros negativos.");
    }
```

Logo, fica da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada! era isso mesmo!